# Crash: Swift, Adding a new Entity on an already existing Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a Core Data, called `TaskManager`, On this CoreData at the moment only one Entity, `Task`: Task got severals attributes:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Task)
class Task: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var context: String
@NSManaged var date: String
@NSManaged var detail: String
@NSManaged var id: String
@NSManaged var responsable: String
@NSManaged var status: String
@NSManaged var summary: String

}
```

If I add a new Entity , for example `User`:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(User)
class User: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var id: String
@NSManaged var name: String
```

}

and I `Reset contents and settings...` from the emulator to let it know the new Entity, my application starts but I can't do anything, it's just frozen, can't click on buttons, the UITableView scroll doesn't work, when I stop the emulator to uninstall the application I can't, holding left click does nothing... I have to delete the Entity from my coredata, move to trash the `NSManagedObject` User auto generated by my Core Data, close the emulator, restart everything and there it works again, but what I need is to work with this other entity, User, so deleting it is... quite dumb..

How am I supposed to do to create the new Entity without freezing all the application?

Thank you for your help.

Regards.
Fselva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you change your data model, you must uninstall your app on the device or on the simulator.
Thus, in the next build and run, the updated DB will be loaded. Of course, you lose all the data being loaded in the precedent version.

Comment: I have read something like this but even if I uninstall and reinstall my app on the simulator the application still freeze X/

Comment: Would copy/paste your system log please ?

Comment: I supposed I made miss manipulations.. I have first stopped the emulator, then uninstalled the app. Then I created my new entity, created the NSManagesObject class for the new entity. Then I did "reset contents and settings" of the emulator and it worked, thanks for all.